# Replaceable 3rd party services

Tags: c#, .net

We are refactoring and upgrading a system that heavily relies on 3rd party integrated services. The problem is that client changes the service providers quite frequently, for example swithes from one SMS service provider to another. Each provider has different API's with different parameteres and methods, what is the best way to make switching less painfull?

We've already tried to create a unified interfaces for all 3rd party services, which allows to predefine a set of methods that each 3rd party service wrapper should implement, but the problem is that different services has different parameters and return values.

What we also tried is to make all methods receive a single parameter - a class implementing an interface IArgs, and then an additional adapter class that implements the ISmsService which casts the args to a required type and passes it to a service wrapper class. But there's too much overhead, as you need to create a args class per method.

```cs
// common interface
public interface ISmsService 
{
   Task<int> Send(string phoneNumber, string text);
}

//external rest service1 wrapper class
public class SmsService1 : ISmsService
{
   public int Send(string text, string phoneNumber)
   {
      //call rest endpoint here
   }
}

// external rest service 2 wrapper class
public class SmsService2
{
   public string Send(int clientId, string countryCode, string phoneNumber, string text)
   {
      //call rest endpoint here
   }
}


//actual service call
this._smsService.Send("123456789", "Hello");

//switch to
this._smsService.Send(12, "21", "123456789", "Hello");
```

What is the correct way of implementing such approach?

Comment: Try asking your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You might get an answer faster there.

Comment: Do i understand right that all relevant data passed by the invoker is the recipient number and text and everything else is specific to the provider? In this case you have your interface and everything else (all provider specific parameters are subject to the wrapper and imho should not be passed from the invoker).

Comment: That's just an example (maybe not the best one). In other external services parameters may be completely different for the same action, that is the biggest problem

Comment: @Matt No. I would close this question there.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Isn't there some other code design stack/board for questions like this?

Comment: @Matt I only know Code Review rules. I'm not going to recommend a site I have no knowledge on and have the OPs question downvoted an closed. That only leads to a bad experience for the OP.

Comment: @Matt the same question had been asked on Code Review and was deleted by the OP (otherwise it would have been closed as example code). IMO a good fit for this question would be https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but OP should read their help-center first.

Comment: @Heslacher That's the one! Could not remember the name of the stack/board.

Answer (score 0):

the declared field `_smsService` should be of type of your declared interface: `ISmsService`, you make your life easier by using dependency injection for instantiation.

The invoker then always calls `this._smsService.Send("123456789", "Hello");`

All the required parameters must be loaded by the appropriate implementation for exampe inside the constructor from a configuration. This way each wrapper has the `Send` method with the same signature and all provider specific parameters are hidden to the caller.